# Can't get online accounts to work from behind proxy

Tags: 13.04, proxy, empathy, online-accounts

At work I am behind a proxy and I can't access my online accounts. I have setup my proxy globally but still no luck connecting to any accounts.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug reported. I don't think it was corrected.

[Empathy Bug Page - Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/304889)